# How do I import existing products into Craft Commerce with the FeedMe or Import plugins?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, import, plugin-feedme, plugin-import

I get it that there are hooks, but i can't get enough inside the differences between entries and product, and actually hack together an extension for either of those plugins.

Comment: This newly released plugin supports importing products into Craft Commerce https://craftpl.us/plugins/productimport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feed Me only supports Entries at this stage. Its on the short-term roadmap in allow importing into all Elements, including Commerce Products. This cannot be achieved through hooks at the moment. Keep an eye on the [plugin page](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe).

Update: FeedMe 2.0 now supports multiple entry types, including Commerce Products: http://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme/getting-started/introduction